# Installing themes from an external website

Tags: themes

**What I am doing**

I am looking for WP theme for an android app. As I couldn't find any searching on WP I looked up on Google and I found that every Theme I found are not available on WP theme search.

An example of this is this [webiste](http://www.apptamin.com/websites-mobile-apps/apptamin-a-more/)

**So, worring on the quality/security of these themes:**

Why are they not available?

Regards,

Comment: It's ok and possible by uploading themes via ftp. I'm going to flag your question, suggesting to close it, because of it's quality, see [ask] and the [help] in general to improve it.

Comment: What do you mean by "WP theme search" precisely?

Comment: @ialocin just a question. Why do they not offer their themes on wordpress.org?

Comment: You really should ask them, because how should I know?

Comment: @Rast When I look for a theme on WP I go to themes page and click "install themes" label. Once there I search for themes. My question is why there are themes on sites that are not offering the same theme on WP site.. Regards!

Comment: @ialocin You should't. It's just a question.

Comment: Yeah, I know, good luck finding out.

Comment: Themes have to undergo a review process to be listed on wordpress.org, it's possible they didn't pass that review.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is **don´t do it if you can avoid it**. You could be installing dangerous code on the server.

Answer based on the analysis done on this [blog](http://wpmu.org/why-you-should-never-search-for-free-wordpress-themes-in-google-or-anywhere-else/).